# Is chest loot in "real gold" or "gold tokens"?

Tags: gloomhaven

I looted a chest and looked up the reward in the back to find "10 gold". Does that mean that I add 10 gold to my character right away, or do I get 10 "gold tokens" which are multiplied based on the difficulty level at the end of the scenario?

Comment: The rulebook refers to "money tokens" and "gold" separately, with the former being converted to the latter at the end of the scenario. My reading would be that finding "X gold" during a scenario is simply that amount of gold and would not be further converted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

user30903 is correct that the rules are consistent in referring to the tokens as "money tokens", so it seems safe to assume that the gold amount for looting a chest is fixed, and does not get multiplied based on the difficulty level of the scenario.

Comment: This is the assumption we've made, but haven't been able to find anything to actually support that.